# Piecewise function find f' and f"

Tags: calculus

Suppose
$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cr}
e^{-1/x^2} & x \neq 0\\
0 & x = 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Show that $f^\prime(0)$ exists and is equal to $0$, also verify that $f^{\prime\prime}$ exists and is equal to $0$.

Do I solve this by finding the left and right side limits of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $0$?

Comment: Yes, and you do the same for f' as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can solve this problem by directly using the definition of the derivative as follows $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$ implies $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x}=0.$$ The same to $f''(0)$.

Comment: And the same to fn(0), which is the nth derivative. All of them are zero

Comment: @imranfat: Nice complement! :)

Answer (score 0):

Note sure if you have seen this limit definition of the derivative, let me know if you want me to explain further.

Note that
$$
f'(x_0) = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0}
$$

So let's look at $f'(0)$:

$$
f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}
$$

Now you have to evaluate this limit properly and the such - since another guy answered before I clicked submit I'll add a little bit more information:

In order to evaluate the limit I would suggest using L'Hôpital's rule. By this rule we know

$$
\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}
$$

given that $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to x_0} g(x) = 0$ or $\pm \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists where $g'(x) \neq 0 \; \forall \; x \neq 0$.

It appears your limit follows these conditions, so it appears you can use this theorem.